# Multi-kinect calibration using ARToolKit

Tags: c++, kinect, camera-calibration, calibration, artoolkit

`ARToolKitPlus::TrackerMultiMarker getModelViewMatrix()`

Using `ArToolKit`, I want to calibrate two Kinect cameras which are placed opposite of each other. Currently, I'm using a board having different pattern on both sides. On both the sides, the patterns consist of squares of equal size.

[image]

First of all, I want to know how `ARToolKit` works. `getModelViewMatrix()` gives a transformation of Kinect with respect some point on the board. But exactly where?
When two Kinects are placed on the same side of the pattern, then its all working fine. I got transformation with respect to a *common point* somewhere.

But for cameras facing each other, I am getting a point-cloud with a deviation mainly along the line connecting them (z-axis).

- Is it because of the width of the board (nearly 4mm)?
- How is it giving even that result? Won't that "common" point on the board differ for both the cameras? One guess is that it calculates the plane on which the feature point lies.
- Does it really matter if we have different patterns on both the sides?
- Will the same pattern on both sides correct the problem? Will it matter if those pattern are not correctly aligned (some displacement along y-axis)?

An idea is to use a hollow checkerboard. But here as well, I have a doubt if `ARToolKit` works with only black and white pattern. Is it possible to perform depth analysis (instead of color) to identify feature points.